# Send a bunch of key-value parameters in google analytic event

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, mixpanel

I'm using Mixpanel in my website for analytic purposes, which is great - I can attach a javascript object to each event I'm sending them, without limitations on the number of keys, and then query those on their platform.
I also need to implement Google Analytics, and I couldn't find anything similar to what Mixpanel is doing. The nearest thing was custom variables, which allow me only to attach only 5 to each event, which isn't good enough.
Is there any way to send an object using Google Analytics, and later on use those parameters when analyzing the data?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but.  Google analytics does have event tracking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upgrade to Universal Analytics you'll have 20 custom dimension and metrics. However there is no way to send a complex variable like a json object to GA (you could send multiple values as a string and use regular expression to filter by parts of that string).

Google does not allow you to sent data that could potentially identify a person, so GA cannot do what mixpanel does in any case.